# TypeError: 'dict_values' object does not support indexing while calling layer from combo box- pyqgis-qgisplugin

Tags: python

while i am calling layer from combo box, throwing an error like this. 
An error has occurred while executing Python code:

TypeError: 'dict_values' object does not support indexing 
Traceback (most recent call last):
    selectedLayer = layers[selectedLayerIndex1].layer()
TypeError: 'dict_values' object does not support indexing

Python version: 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) [MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD64)] 
QGIS version: 3.4.15-Madeira Madeira, e83d02e274

code
 selectedLayerIndex1 = self.dlg.comboBox.currentIndex()

selectedLayer = layers[selectedLayerIndex1].layer()

qgis vrsion: QGIS version: 3.4.15-Madeira Madeir

Comment: I think questions about PyQGIS are more on-topic at the [gis.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Index, you have to iterate layers first and add them in the layersList. Only after thar you can use index and choose layers from list (using Index)

Use this code in def `run(self)`:

```py
layers_list = []
curLayers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values()
for layer in curLayers:
    layers_list.append(layer)


def chooseIndex():
    sLayerIndex = self.dockwidget.comboBox.currentIndex()
    selectedLayer = layers_list[sLayerIndex]
    print(selectedLayer)

self.dockwidget.comboBox.currentIndexChanged.connect(chooseIndex)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the particular problem but after some research it appears that in Python 3 calling the 'values()' method on a dictionary DOES NOT returns a list, it instead returns a 'dict_values' object.
Said 'dict_values' object DOES NOT support indexed access, check out it's documentation for more information.

Comment: May I get more idea about it. Then how can I utilize layer from combo box.

Comment: @sreeraj Sorry but I have no clue what it is. My guess would be that layers is not a dictionary nor a list but rather a 'dict_values' object. I cant find anything about that object

Comment: @sreeraj No problem!If you think it answered your question please mark it as such. Good luck